# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' Using Webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass, webpack-file-loader

Hi im using socket io in my application. Which is requiring fs. when i try to bundle my javascript using below webpack config. im getting error can not resolve 'fs'.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'my application path/node_modules/socket.io/lib'
```

i found by adding `target:'node'` and `node:{fs:'empty'}`. this issue got resolved.

But there is an issue in sass-loader. Getting below error.

```
ERROR in javascript/bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (zlibLimiter) [javascript/bundle.js:60019,4]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin ../../../node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist ../../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--2-2!../../../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!s
```

running the application ignoring above error. getting below error.

```
external "crypto":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.__decorate (external "crypto":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 93620a17882f7a2aa1d3:19)
    at Object.byteToHex (rng.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 93620a17882f7a2aa1d3:19)
```

Below is my webpack config and versions. Can some one please help me to resolve this issue.

"webpack": "~3.6.0",
npm -v 5.8.0
node -v v8.4.0

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'css/[name].css',
  allChunks: false
});


let output = {
  path: __dirname + '/src/main/resources/static/',
  filename: 'javascript/[name].js'
};

if (env === 'debug' || env === 'nondev') {
  output = {
    path: __dirname + '/target/classes/static/',
    filename: 'javascript/[name].js'
  };
}

let config = {
  context: __dirname + '/app/js/src',
  entry: {
    bundle: './index.jsx',
    application: './static/scss/application.scss',
    'application-pdap': './static/scss/application-pdap.scss'
  },
  output: output,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/js/src/static/scss')],
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          publicPath: '../',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                minimize: true,
                sourceMap: false
              }
            },
            {loader: 'sass-loader'}
          ],
          fallback: 'style-loader'
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [extractSass],

};

if (env === 'production' || env === 'nondev') {
  config.devtool = 'nosources-source-map';

  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {NODE_ENV: '"production"'}
    })
  );

  config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {warnings: false},
    comments: false,
    sourceMap: false,
    minimize: false
  }));
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: You should accept the submitted answer or explain why it didn't work for you

Answer (score 8):

The solution depends on the type of application you want to build. Usually front-end and back-end JavaScript code are bundled separately, effectively creating two output bundles.

#### Front-end

For a frontend/web project, add the [socket.io client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) libary to your app bundle. There is no need to include any node dependencies (`fs`) or mock entries like `node: { fs:'empty' }`. You can choose `target:'web`' or leave it out, as it is the default.

#### Back-end

Pick [`target:'node'`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/) and install [socket.io server](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) library. You do not need to specify `externals: ["fs"]` as shown in the other answer, because `target: 'node'` will take care of not bundling `path`, `fs` and other built-in modules.

Better avoid `npm i fs` - this is a needless escape hatch and a security risk. There have already happened cases of malicious npm packages with common package names.

You could even deliberate about, wether a node backend bundle is needed at all. An alternative is to install [`webpack-node-externals`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals), which treats either all or specific npm packages as ["externals"](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) and excludes them from the bundle:

```
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  target: 'node', // ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
  externals: [nodeExternals()], // ignore all modules in node_modules folder
  // ...
};
```

This makes sense for the back-end, as all dependencies are installed in `node_modules` at server start time and don't need to be included in the bundle.

#### Exclude files from loaders

To exclude files from certain loaders and their transformations, you can use [`exclude`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleexclude) module rule. An example is to omit `node_modules` from `babel-loader` transformations:

```
{ test: /\.(jsx|js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
```

[Further reading](https://medium.com/code-oil/webpack-javascript-bundling-for-both-front-end-and-back-end-b95f1b429810)

Comment: This is a much better solution!

Comment: To anyone interested in loading socket.io in the browser, the solution is to use the socket.io-client module which doesn't require fs

Comment: correct answer imo

Answer (score 2):

Just install fs (npm i fs), and add at your webpack config

```
externals: ["fs"],
```

Comment: Isn't `fs` available by default? Why `npm i fs` ?

Comment: This error occurs while webpack trying to retrive socket.io module., and search requred libs at current socket.io catalog. And if You do not have fs installed at current projects directory, you should install it.

Comment: Not sure that this is safe to do anymore. Note from NPM:

"This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by another package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you want it."

Comment: Best working answer IMO, as it does not require loading node.

Comment: Doesn't work any more "Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined
    at eval (external "fs"?a40d:1)"

Comment: Downvoted, this seems like a very bad advice. At best, it's a shady workaround, at worse, it's a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still facing this issue, you can try the following workaround. Update your webpack file to including the following configuration:

```
node: {
    fs: 'empty',
}
```

We had a similar issue within our project and adding this specific configuration resolved the 'fs' related error in webpack.
It's also worth checking the version of Webpack version. we had to revert back the webpack and webpack cli versions to `4.0.0` and `4.2.0` respectively.